# How to install avconv with libfdk_aac on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ffmpeg, avconv, aac

How to install or compile avconv with libfdk_aac on Ubuntu 14.04 ? I am also ok with comparable aac codecs e.g. http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Fraunhofer_FDK_AAC

Currently I am trying this but with avconv: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

I let you know how it works out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's how I do it. But I must warn you, this requires a little courage as you must build libav (This will give you the avconv executable among other tools) yourself. But have no fear, I have done it many times and I'll show you how to to build and install everything without messing your system up. If you don't want your custom libav build anymore, all you have to do is delete a directory.

### Prerequisites

First I remove the avconv installed buy default with:

```
apt-get remove --purge libav-tools
```

Then make sure you have the required tools for building software in general:

```
apt-get install build-essential
```

To get the fastest avconv possible you'll need an assembly compiler. That's easy:

```
apt-get install yasm
```

Now get into a scrap directory to build in, I'll do:

```
mkdir ~/src
cd ~/src
```

Now clone the libav git repo (you'll need git installed for this):

```
git clone git://git.libav.org/libav.git
```

This will give you the the latest and greatest libav source, I have found the bleeding edge code stable enough for my needs and haven't run into any code related bugs during building.

Let the repo clone and then install libfdk-aac through the package manager:

```
apt-get install libfdk-aac-dev
```

To make things simple lets just install the libx264 library for avconv to use:

```
apt-get install libx264-dev
```

Create a home for the binaries and other files that will be built in a moment
(This will make things easy to uninstall as well):

```
mkdir ~/apps
```

Once installed, the avconv executable will be located in ~/apps/bin/
To run avconv from the command line simply add ~/apps/bin to you $PATH

### Installation

Now you, need to configure the libav source to use your newly install fdk-aac library.
Simply enter this in the command line:

```
./configure \
--prefix=~/apps \
--enable-nonfree \
--enable-gpl \
--disable-shared \
--enable-static \
--enable-libx264 \
--enable-libfdk-aac
```

This command will give you all of libav default encoding and decoding libraries plus
libx264 and libfdk_aac
Note: should you want more encoding functionality try ./configure --help to see all the external libraries you can enable.

Now all thats left to do is build the thing!
This should only take a few minutes on a decent machine.

```
make && make install
```

If you added ~/apps/bin to you $PATH you should be able to run 'avconv' now.

To update your custom libav build, just run:

```
git pull origin
```

In ~/src/libav/ up pull the latest code. Then reconifgure with the command above, make and make install.

Should you every want to get rid of you custom build and reinstall ubuntu's default libav-tools packages run:

```
rm -rf ~/apps/
apt-get install libav-tools
```

And remove ~/apps/bin from your $PATH

Sorry if the task you want to achieve seems daunting, but it makes me proud to use a custom built, bleeding edge version of avconv :) I think the extra work pays off. Hope this helps :)

### Verification

Verify it is installed correctly with:

```
avconv -codecs | grep aac
```

You want to see:

```
AAC (Advanced Audio Coding) (decoders: aac libfdk_aac ) (encoders: aac libfdk_aac )
```

### Usage

```
avconv -f alsa -i default -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 256k filename.aac
```

*Please note that the infamous experimental flag is now not necessary nor recommended anymore.*

You want to see:

```
  Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc58.12.1 libfdk_aac
```

Comment: I find it better to create a `~/bin` directory and keep everything there (my installed software, my written shell scripts, etc). I then place it at the *beginning* of $PATH, allowing me to keep the installed packages, but yet work with the bleeding edge stuff as well.

Comment: It's more convenient to include `--enable-libmp3lame` as the parameter of `./configure` as well if you foresee a need to output MP3.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing this and added the Usage part.

Comment: Half of these commands need `sudo` prefix to work. Other half doesn’t.

Answer (score 4):

Or if you want to use the inferiour aac:

```
sudo apt-get install libav-tools
```

Then instead of using the Fraunhofer use these switches:

```
-acodec aac -strict experimental or -acodec libvo_aacenc
```

Audio quality may vary.